# No matter what I try I cant print the value I keep getting it <__main__.card object at -->

Tags: python

I am trying to add card c to deck d but I can't print the deck instead I keep getting `<__main__.card at >`

```
class Card():
        def __init__(self,theName,theMoves):
            self.name = theName
            self.moves = list(theMoves)
        
    
class Deck():
        theCards = [] 
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def addCard(self,theCard):
            Deck.theCards.append(theCard)
            print(Deck.theCards)
    
    #adding card to my deck
    c = Card("sh",["fire",258])
    d = Deck()
    d.addCard(c)
```

Comment: try using .data with it. c.data. Its an object with 'data' attribute in it which contains actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over your cards and call vars() on them, because printing a list of objects just shows you only certain memory addresses but no properties. Instead of:

```py
print(Deck.theCards)
```

use a loop similar to this one:

```py
for card in Deck.theCards:
    print(vars(card))
```

which prints all variables and their corresponding values of an object. I also assume you want to have different decks of different players, but your code currently saves the list of cards within the class definition. Thusly all objects of type Deck you create with the Deck() call are sharing the same list of cards. Lets say you add another deck:

```py
#adding card to my deck
print("player 1")
c = Card("sh",["fire",258])
d = Deck()
d.addCard(c)

print("player 2")
c2 = Card("it",["water",258])
d2 = Deck()
d2.addCard(c2)
```

The deck of player 2 also includes the cards of player 1 and vice versa. The printed output of the suggested code extension:

```py
player 1
{'name': 'sh', 'moves': ['fire', 258]}
player 2
{'name': 'sh', 'moves': ['fire', 258]}
{'name': 'it', 'moves': ['water', 258]}
```

The user 'insert random' already offered a solution before. To get two different decks with two different lists of cards you have to store the card list(s) within the class instance, not the class definition. Here the whole updated code:

```py
class Card():
        def __init__(self,theName,theMoves):
            self.name = theName
            self.moves = list(theMoves)

class Deck():
        def __init__(self):
            self.theCards = [] 
        def addCard(self,theCard):
            self.theCards.append(theCard)
            for card in self.theCards:
              print(vars(card))

#adding card to my deck
print("player 1")
c = Card("sh",["fire",258])
d = Deck()
d.addCard(c)

print("player 2")
c2 = Card("it",["water",258])
d2 = Deck()
d2.addCard(c2)
```

Note that self is used instead of Deck to store a different card list for every new deck created with the Deck() call. This list is created by the initial class constructor function not by the class definition itself.
Console output:

```py
player 1
{'name': 'sh', 'moves': ['fire', 258]}
player 2
{'name': 'it', 'moves': ['water', 258]}
```

Which is I guess what you want.
Version with dictionaries:

```py
#adding card to my deck
print("player 1")
c = {'name': 'sh', 'moves':["fire",258] }
d = { 'theCards': [c] }
print(list(card for card in d['theCards']))

print("player 2")
c2 = {'name': 'it', 'moves':["water",258] }
d2 = { 'theCards': [c2] }
print(list(card for card in d2['theCards']))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not referring to the specific class instance in your class functions. Change your `Deck` class definition as follows:

```
class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.theCards = []
    def addCard(self, theCard):
        self.theCards.append(theCard)
        print(self.theCards)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, when Python prints a list it prints the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of the list's elements.  For many objects, including custom classes, the default `repr` looks like

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f00ff75fd00>
```

You can override this behaviour by defining a `__repr__` method on your classes.  Conventionally, the output of `__repr__` should be a string that would produce your object if it were passed to [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

For the card class, it would look like this:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, theName, theMoves):
        self.name = theName
        self.moves = list(theMoves)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Card('{}', {})".format(self.name, self.moves)
```

Giving this output to your script (once you have fixed the indentation):

```
[Card('sh', ['fire', 258])]
```

You can also define a `__str__` method to customise how your object appears when `str(myobject)` is called.  If `__str__` is not defined Python will use `__repr__` instead.

Comment: __str__ of an object is not called when you print a list of objects, only __repl__ is. But you have to be careful with __repl__, you already mentioned it. As a beginner I would stay with a loop instead of overriding __repl__.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an indentation error. Your declaration of `c`, `d` and `d.addCard(c)` should be spaced indented back once. The same needs to go for everything inside your `Card` and `Deck` class.

```
class Card():
    def __init__(self,theName,theMoves):
        self.name = theName
        self.moves = list(theMoves)


class Deck():
    theCards = []
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def addCard(self,theCard):
        Deck.theCards.append(theCard)
        print(Deck.theCards)

#adding card to my deck
c = Card("sh",["fire",258])
d = Deck()
d.addCard(c)
```

Comment: but there is no indentation error showing in terminal